# Getting the Job Run Datetime in a Scheduled Glue Job

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

Is there a way to get run date time of a glue job that is scheduled (using CRON) inside the job? Like a default argument that passes the time and date of the job run?

```
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME", "START_TIME?"])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no default argument for that, you would have to pass it manually through the job parameters.

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-glue-arguments.html) is an overview about the default parameters.

Comment: If the job is scheduled using CRON, how do you send the jobrun date as argument?

Comment: You can't get the job start and end time within the same glue job. One option is that you can always use the system time to log when the job started and when it ended. Otherwise, you should use the JobRun API to get the job metadata and status.